# Transforming selected text with a hotkey

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys, textselection

I have this code:

myVariable

which I want to change into

trace("myVariable: " + myVariable);

using a direct hotkey like <kbd>alt</kbd> - <kbd>f12</kbd> to do it. I.e not using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>space</kbd> and arrow buttons.

is it possible in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to bind hotkeys for templates. One way for somewhat similar behavior could be using proper template name and "insert automatically"..

That is, you would write *trcc* (for example) and Eclipse would automatically expand it to a template *trace("${name}: " + ${name});* (and you would end up editing the name). The drawback is that you should choose such a name that you won't use it otherwise in the code. (So if you would end up writing trcc for other things, you should choose another name)

Regarding to the templates, [one blog entry on them](http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C1281128591/E20070302212710/index.html). (Note the ${enclosing_type} and  ${enclosing_method} if you're not familiar with them already)